# Need to fetch last word from two file using batch script and mail (or) display

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file, which will fetch last word from two files.
Open a file and fetch the last word and mail to me. Currently with the below code , file is opening. Kindly help to complete.

```
:Variables
set CURRENT_DATE=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%

for %%X in ("\\plserver01\GO\04052017\"*AmbFile1*.DAT) do notepad %%X
for %%W in ("\\plserver01\GO\04052017\"*BvtFile2*.DAT) do notepad %%W

pause
```

Regards,
Chs.

Comment: most SO questions like this fall under "homework" (notice the quotes).  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions What kind of things have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

using notepad won't help, because your batchfile can not communicate with notepad. Use native batch to get the words:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%X in (file1.txt) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "OneLast=%%Y"
for /f "delims=" %%X in (file2.txt) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "TwoLast=%%Y"
echo last words in the two files are: %OneLast% and %TwoLast%
```

For how to send a mail, use our [search box](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+mail) on top of the page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I tried as below, which you have given

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I tried as below, which you have given Hi, Thanks for the update. I didn't get the files opened and got the value , the output is as given in quotes "last words in the two files are:  and ", I think it may be a problem due to the space after the last word in the fil. please guide should i modify  the code `@echo off
'code' for /f "delims=" %%X in (\\pl\IL\Archive\GO\05052017\JIGF.JLB28.20170505.DAT) do for %%Y 

in (%%X) do set "OneLast=%%Y"  'code'


echo last words in the two files are: %OneLast% and %TwoLast% `
due to space i did not given the second file.

Comment: Huh? You tried a completely different code. Use `for /?` to find out, what your code really does (hint: it doesn't make any sense)

Comment: I have replaced only the file path in your code and tried as given here. The file did not open. Clarify , If I am wrong.    ` :Variables set CURRENT_DATE=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4% pause @echo off for /f "delims=" %%X in (\\pl\IL\Ar\GO\07052017\ILL.20170507070447.DAT) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "OneLast=%%Y" for /f "delims=" %%X in (\\pl\IL\Ar\GO\07052017\ILL.20170507080404.DAT) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "TwoLast=%%Y" echo last words in the two files are: %OneLast% and %TwoLast% pause` –

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. I didn't get the files opened and got the value , the output is as given in quotes "last words in the two files are: and ", I think it may be a problem due to the space after the last word in the fil. please guide should i modify the code `@echo off  for /f "delims=" %%X in (\\pl\IL\Archive\GO\05052017\JIGF.JLB28.20170505.DAT) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "OneLast=%%Y"  echo last words in the two files are: %OneLast% and %TwoLast%`  due to space i did not given the second file.

Comment: I have replaced only the file path in your code and tried as given here. The file did not open. Clarify , If I am wrong.                                                                 
`
 :Variables
set CURRENT_DATE=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%
pause

@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%X in (\\pl\IL\Ar\GO\07052017\ILL.20170507070447.DAT) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "OneLast=%%Y"

for /f "delims=" %%X in (\\pl\IL\Ar\GO\07052017\ILL.20170507080404.DAT) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "TwoLast=%%Y"

echo last words in the two files are: %OneLast% and %TwoLast%

pause`

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced only the file path in your code and tried as given here. The file did not open. Clarify , If I am wrong. I know DotNet but totally new to batch script.

```
 :Variables
set CURRENT_DATE=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%
pause

@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%X in (\\pl\IL\Ar\GO\07052017\ILL.20170507070447.DAT) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "OneLast=%%Y"

for /f "delims=" %%X in (\\pl\IL\Ar\GO\07052017\ILL.20170507080404.DAT) do for %%Y in (%%X) do set "TwoLast=%%Y"

echo last words in the two files are: %OneLast% and %TwoLast%

pause
```

[image]

Comment: both files existing? Both non-empty?

Comment: Hi,Both file are existing, at the end of file, empty space is there. Hope it should not be an issue.

Comment: no, the second `for` should take care of this. How are the files encoded?